# What Jars Included With jasperreports-4.5.1.jar

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, netbeans-7

I am new to Jasper Reports. I have included many jars with jasperreports-4.5.1 but am getting different exception each time when i included different jar file in my class path. Please tell which jars i include  with jasperreports-4.5.1.jar so that i donot get any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it on the Maven repository.  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/4.5.1

Comment: Thanks @phatfingers but still i get following exception Could not connect to the database: No suitable driver found for CatalogNew No suitable driver found for CatalogNew Apr 26, 2012 11:54:12 AM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter <init> WARNING: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null

Comment: I'm not familiar with JasperReports, but it likely wants you to register a JDBC driver to a database of your choosing.  Often a JDBC driver is not made a direct dependency to allow the flexibility of that choice.

Comment: This page might be of some help:  http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/DataSources

Comment: please give  my question upvote as i also accpted your answer.

Comment: Generally, an upvote to a question isn't awarded as a matter of quid-pro-quo, but as an indicator of whether the question might help others facing a similar issue.